# Only allow a link to be clickable if checkbox is selected

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, hyperlink

I'm trying to setup a button/link that is only clickable if a checkbox is selected. So my code so far would be

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox">By clicking this you agree that you are adding a subscription/recurring product to your order<br>
</form>

<a href="exmaple.com">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</a>
```

I'm assuming I will have to do this in javascript although I'm on a beginner when it comes to javascript. Thanks

Comment: can't we expect a beginning from a beginner ?

Comment: What if someone visits your page who **isn't** using Javascript? How are you going to stop them from clicking the link?

Comment: @Kacey What if this is a question regarding progressive enhancement?

Comment: @KevinBowersox It very well could be. I was merely curious.

Answer (score 2):

This code adds some `id` attributes to the elements to provide some hooks for the Javascript.  It hides and prevents the default action of the anchor until the checkbox is clicked.

**HTML**

```
<form>
<input id="agreement" type="checkbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox">By clicking this you agree that you are adding a subscription/recurring product to your order<br>
</form>

<a href="exmaple.com" id="link">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</a>
```

**Javascript**

```
var chk = document.getElementById("agreement");
var anchor = document.getElementById("link");
anchor.style.display = "none";
anchor.onclick = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
}

chk.onclick = function(){
    if(chk.checked){
        anchor.style.display = "inline";
      anchor.onclick = "";
    }
}
```

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/zVCD7/

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way of doing it using pure javascript, using some ID attributes I added as hooks for the javascript `document.getElementById()` function.

***HTML:***

```
<form>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="agreeCheckbox" name="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox" onchange="toggleLink(this);">By clicking this you agree that you are adding a subscription/recurring product to your order</p>
</form>

<p><a href="exmaple.com" id="agreeLink" style="display:none;">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</a></p>
```

***Javascript:***

```
function toggleLink(checkBox)
{
    var link = document.getElementById("agreeLink");

    if (checkBox.checked)
        link.style.display = "inline";
    else
        link.style.display = "none";
}
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/HLGGJ/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="agreeCheckbox" id="agreeCheckbox" value="agreeCheckbox">By clicking this you agree that you are adding a subscription/recurring product to your order<br>

<div id="mycheck">
<a href="exmaple.com">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</a>
</div>


var check= document.getElementById('agreeCheckbox');
  if (check.checked){
    document.getElementById('mycheck').style.display='block';
  }
else{
 document.getElementById('mycheck').style.display='none';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways you could accomplish this.  Most of the newer methods would probably involve jQuery.

First, include jQuery (Google works):

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then, make the link, not a link:

```
<div id="mylink">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</div>
```

Next, if the box is clicked, make it clickable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("input[name = 'agreeCheckbox']").click(function(){
  $("#mylink").html('<a href="exmaple.com">This link is only clickable if checkbox is checked</a>');
});
</script>
```

Comment: So you recommend adding 30kb+ to the request to toggle an anchor?

Comment: Yes and no.  Odds are, it will help in the long run if writing a lot of javascript, and using the Google hosting, most people already have the library cached.  But you are correct that it's not the most space efficient solution.

Comment: Good point about the CDN.  It depends on the circumstances, usually when some tags JS as the question they are looking for a Native solution.  I would also recommend considering the original posters comfort with the technology, if they are having issues toggling a checkbox, jquery may be out of their technical abilities at this time.

Comment: Good to know.  New to StackOverflow (answering anyway), so I'll keep that in mind.  Thanks.